# ConnectedAppPerms

Tags: api, permissions, connected-apps

Is it possible to set up a custom profile for a connected app? The objective is to provide a developer external to the org with access to opportunities, and only opportunities via cypress automated tests. Right now I have the app he is connected to running on `FULL` scope, and I'm planning to change it to `Perform ANSI SQL queries on Salesforce CDP data (cdp_query_api)` scope.

But wasn't sure if it was possible to have a restrict an app to a single object, or if I have to go the route of building a custom RestResource for the dev.

Thanks for the help!

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5

Comment: The underlying data security at the object/record level is still controlled by the user's profile/perms rather than scope. Try this: grant `full` scope to a user with a Minimal Access profile and see if you can read your Opportunity records, for example.

Comment: Yep. I have been testing this. Using postman, I'm able to query records that are not accessed in his profile.